# How to prevent my screens from dimming (going black) from the command line

Tags: command-line, power-management, dwm

In KDE, there was a system setting where you could specifically set the monitors to never go black.

Now I've switched to dwm and (it might not be related) my screens dim after about 10 minutes. How do I change this setting directly from the command line? I'm guessing this has to do with X?

Comment: Michael's answer is correct, but you might want to investigate _why_ your screen is dimming and address that issue directly.

Comment: @jasonwryan, I assume my monitors are going to sleep due to the lack of input (no keyboard or mouse activity).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the DPMS settings, which are controllable with `xset`. You can disable all DPMS with:

```
$ xset -dpms
```

And re-enable them with:

```
$ xset +dpms
```

You can also control how long before the monitor switches into each state (standby, suspend, and off; they're explained in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling#Design)) by passing 3 integers for the number of seconds before each state should be activated:

```
# Switch to standby after a minute, suspend after two minutes, and off after three minutes
$ xset dpms 60 120 180
```

Setting a time of 0 disables the state, so `-dpms` is equivalent to:

```
$ xset dpms 0 0 0
```

Comment: Awesome, do I need to set that up every time I reboot?

Comment: @Max Yes, but you can put it in a script that runs automatically; for example, `~/.xinitrc` is typically run when X starts

Comment: Actually, I tried and tested this with no results. I ran `xset -dpms` as my normal user and as root and my screens are still dimming.

Answer (score 4):

Not only DPMS can turn the screen off. There is also a built-in screensaver in Xorg. You can turn it off with

xset s off

Comment: This seems like it makes sense, my screensaver could be kicking in (even though I haven't set one). I'll give this a try tonight.