# How to turn off xscreensaver automatically while watching Flash video?

Tags: video, adobe-flash, screensaver

Can I configure Flash to automatically disable xscreensaver while it's playing video? Or, conversely, configure xscreensaver not to trigger while Flash is playing video?

<sup>I've seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18882/how-to-prevent-my-screens-from-dimming-going-black-from-the-command-line) on disabling the screensaver manually.</sup>

Comment: did you try [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18882/how-to-prevent-my-screens-from-dimming-going-black-from-the-command-line) (Looks like a duplicate). If it does not work, mention it in the question.

Comment: I was actually looking on an automatic solution, but doing it manually with such a small command is also an option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find different scripts in order to do that on [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1090393.html). It's quite *hacky* and it does not seem that a clean way exist.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this in the settings for either flash or xscreensaver.  However, is it possible that you are streaming video from another site?  You could write a script that ran netstat and looked for established connections on a certain port or maybe site and then xset s off; xset -dpms ; sleep XXX, then reenable.  Then just background the script.